# How to reshape an array with numpy like this:

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, reshape

I have this:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]])
```

And I would like to reshape my array like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 3]])
```

How do I do it using python numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just split and concatenate:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]])

cols = a.shape[1] // 2
np.concatenate((a[:,:cols], a[:,cols:]))

#[[0 0 1 1]
# [0 0 1 1]
# [2 2 3 3]
# [2 2 3 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply swap rows after reshaping it.

```
a= np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]]).reshape(4,4)

a[[1,2]] = a[[2,1]]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 3]])
```